# How to use MDLP_Discretizer to process a dataset from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program that needs to process a CSV file. This file needs to be converted into a dataset. The example that I am working with comes from the popular python tutorial with the iris data set. I am trying to replace datasets.load_iris() with a method to read the CSV 'A1-md.csv'.

Expected: The program process the CSV and loads the data.

Actual:
The program fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\e_disc.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\e_disc.py", line 27, in main
    discretizer.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "D:\Data Mining\assignment_1\entropy_disc_test\MDLP.py", line 58, in fit
    if len(self._col_idx) != self._data_raw.shape[1]:  # some columns will not be discretized
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

A working example looks like this

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from MDLP import MDLP_Discretizer

def main():

    ######### USE-CASE EXAMPLE #############

    #read dataset
    dataset = datasets.load_iris()
    print(dataset)
    X, y = dataset['data'], dataset['target']
    feature_names, class_names = dataset['feature_names'], dataset['target_names']
    numeric_features = np.arange(X.shape[1])  # all fetures in this dataset are numeric. These will be discretized
    print(f'numeric_feature type {type(numeric_features)}')
    # Split between training and test
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

    # #Initialize discretizer object and fit to training data
    discretizer = MDLP_Discretizer(features=numeric_features)
    discretizer.fit(X_train, y_train)
    X_train_discretized = discretizer.transform(X_train)

    #apply same discretization to test set
    X_test_discretized = discretizer.transform(X_test)

    #Print a slice of original and discretized data
    print('Original dataset:\n%s' % str(X_train[0:5]))
    print('Discretized dataset:\n%s' % str(X_train_discretized[0:5]))

    #see how feature 0 was discretized
    print('Feature: %s' % feature_names[0])
    print('Interval cut-points: %s' % str(discretizer._cuts[0]))
    print('Bin descriptions: %s' % str(discretizer._bin_descriptions[0]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My implementation looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from MDLP import MDLP_Discretizer


def main():

    ######### USE-CASE EXAMPLE #############

    #read dataset
    dataset = pd.read_csv('A1-dm.csv')
    print(dataset)
    X, y = dataset['A1'].to_numpy(), dataset['Class'].to_numpy()
    print(dataset)
    feature_names, class_names = dataset['A1'].to_numpy(), dataset['Class'].to_numpy()
    numeric_features = X  # all fetures in this dataset are numeric. These will be discretized
    print(numeric_features)
    print(f'numeric_feature type {type(numeric_features)}')
    # #Split between training and test
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

    print(numeric_features)
    # #Initialize discretizer object and fit to training data
    discretizer = MDLP_Discretizer(features=numeric_features)
    discretizer.fit(X_train, y_train)
    X_train_discretized = discretizer.transform(X_train)

    # #apply same discretization to test set
    X_test_discretized = discretizer.transform(X_test)

    # #Print a slice of original and discretized data
    print('Original dataset:\n%s' % str(X_train[0:5]))
    print('Discretized dataset:\n%s' % str(X_train_discretized[0:5]))

    # #see how feature 0 was discretized
    print('Feature: %s' % feature_names[0])
    print('Interval cut-points: %s' % str(discretizer._cuts[0]))
    print('Bin descriptions: %s' % str(discretizer._bin_descriptions[0]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I convert my dataset below into a form that is similar to the iris data set?

```
A1,A2,A3,Class
2,0.4631338,1.5,3
8,0.7460648,3.0,3
6,0.264391038,2.5,2
5,0.4406713,2.3,1
2,0.410438159,1.5,3
2,0.302901816,1.5,2
6,0.275869396,2.5,3
8,0.084782428,3.0,3
2,0.53226533,1.5,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using only one feature column (`A1`), you need to reshape the resulting numpy array to a column vector (`reshape(-1, 1)`) and use the `np.arange` and `X.shape[1]` contained in the working example.

```py
X, y = dataset['A1'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1), dataset['Class'].to_numpy()
numeric_features = np.arange(X.shape[1])
```

If your intention was to use all the features in the CSV file (`A1`, `A2`, `A3`) you don't need to reshape the resulting numpy array, you only need to pass the list of Pandas columns that represent the features (`dataset[['A1','A2','A3']]`).

```py
...
#read dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('iris_as_csvfile.csv')
print(dataset)
X, y = dataset[['A1','A2','A3']].to_numpy(), dataset['Class'].to_numpy()
print(dataset)
numeric_features = np.arange(X.shape[1])  # all fetures in this dataset are numeric. These will be discretized
...
```

As a side note, you can get the column names used in the CSV file using Pandas [`columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html).

```py
...
feature_names = dataset.columns[:-1].to_list()
# ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
class_names = dataset.columns[-1]
# 'Class'
...
...
```

Output:

```py
Original dataset:
[[4.9 2.4]
 [5.4 3.4]
 [4.9 3.6]
 [6.4 3.1]
 [5.2 2.7]]
Discretized dataset:
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
Feature: A1
Interval cut-points: [5.55]
Bin descriptions: {0: {0: '-inf_to_5.55', 1: '5.55_to_inf'}}
```